"CMake Options Visibility Configuration" What should i do?
problem
I press "ctrl+shift+p" and choosing ">cmake: quick start" then i get this problem. Don't know what should i configure. Even after changing from "hidden" to "visibile" i have this issue.
my visibility options
Sorry for my english.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It's just notifying you that the UI and some settings related to the status bar and view for the CMake Tools extension changed (IIRC, that was a while ago, but I guess recent enough that they still include the code that shows that notification). Once you've adjusted your settings, you can click "Do Not Show Again", or manually edit the cmake.showOptionsMovedNotification to set it to false.
Documentation about the visibility options of CMake Tools can be found at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-options-configuration.md.
